# Fancybox3 image after close website font loosing

Tags: php, jquery, html, fancybox-3

I am using Fancybox 3.0 to open some images on a website. I use this code in head tags:

```
    <!-- INCLUDE FANCYBOX -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox3/dist/jquery.fancybox.css"> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="./fancybox3/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

And the body code is:
< a data-fancybox href="image.jpg" >
xxxx
< /a >

When i click on xxxx link, the image is opening in a fancybox popup, but after i close the image pressing X button, all of my websites fonts are changing smaller or greater in some divs. How can i solve this annoying problem ???

Thanks

Comment: I never heard some problem like that with Fancy box. Si, I think it is a consequence from the rest of your code. Please provide us à JSFidle reproducing this problem.

Comment: Yes, please, show your page. I have no idea what could cause this.

Comment: I have solve it. It was due to css style in body tag. I removed it and now it works perfectly